# Запятая перед "чем"

Tags: пунктуация

Поясните чем руководствоваться при проверке соответствия требований к противопожарному расстоянию от производственных зданий до открытых площадок для хранения автомобилей, а также автостоянок.

Answer (score 5):

Запятая перед *чем* нужна, так как она отделяет главную часть от придаточной в сложноподчиненном предложении.

Answer (score 1):

Поясните, чем руководствоваться при проверке соответствия требований к противопожарному расстоянию от производственных зданий до открытых площадок для хранения автомобилей, а также автостоянок

Answer (score 1):

Запятая перед ЧЕМ нужна, так как она отделяет главную часть от придаточной изъяснительной в сложноподчиненном предложении:поясните ЧТО?...